# Getting the last database entry with sql is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

My database has two columns : time and work. Its very very large and still growing.

I want to select the last entry:

```
$sql = "SELECT time, work FROM device ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1"
```

It takes 1.5 seconds to response it. **How can I speed this up?.** Because I repeat it 20 times.

I can't wait 20 seconds.

Greetings!

Comment: I presume that you have indexed the time column? Also, take a look at why you are doing the same thing 20 times (if you are), you might find a way of speeding things up by 95% right there.

Comment: If you really only select whose 2 columns, add a covering index on both columns, not only on time. Will be even faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `MAX`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM device)
```

add also an `Index` on column `time`

---

*I was wondering why do you want to repeat this 20 times. If you are working on the application lebel, maybe you can add the result in a variable so you won't execute it again.*

Comment: The time column is timestamp and i want the last work entry. So i need to order it by time

Comment: @JW Great, have your +1 now :)

Comment: @ JW : I have 20 devices. I collect time and voltage/amperage at every second. I can watch the trend. But first I need to choice a device. I collect them all in a table. On column is the last time e.g.

Comment: @Susanne92 did you add an index on column `time`?

Comment: do you want to get all devices with their latest `time` on just one query?

Comment: @Susanne92: are the date for 2 different devices in 2 different tables or all in the same table?

Comment: Hello :) There is no index on column time

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do this. But now i get it one after one

Comment: @Susanne92 try adding, and see the difference.

Comment: @Susanne92 try executing this, `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX (time);`

Comment: Thanks it helped! But I developed a different solution. I created a new datatable where the last value is automatically updated! Thank you all for helping me!